# Liquibase: Error update Function/Store procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, liquibase, sql-function

I use Liquibase on Mysql and got a below error when trying create function

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'in varchar2) return varchar2
>   is

This is my function file MyFunction.sql:

```
create or replace function MyFuncion(p_id in varchar2) 
return varchar2 is Result varchar2(50);
begin   Result := 'bbbb' || p_id;  
return(Result); end MyFuncion;
```

End my changelog

```
<changeSet author="taibc" id="sqlFile-example2">
    <sqlFile dbms="ttdp_thanh, mysql"
            encoding="utf8"
            endDelimiter="\n/" 
            path="MyFunction.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile="true"
            splitStatements="true"
            stripComments="true"/>
      <rollback>
        DROP Function MyFunction;         
    </rollback>     
</changeSet>
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: probably you have to have `/` at the ed of your file

Comment: and also remove in from `(p_id in varchar2)`